# Saving json file on server using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am building an application where a user can upload a JSON file and visualise it on one click (`Build a network` button). I realize I need to save the file on my server before visualizing it. I'm trying to do this by using `saveAs()` from FileSaver.js.

It works but the file is downloaded with the name 'download', no file extension and to the Downloads folder. How can I fix this? Is this a correct way to solve a task like that?

UPD: I'd like to avoid saving the user file on the server if it's possible to build a visualization from the file right away.

```js
document.getElementById('import').onclick = function() {
 var files = document.getElementById('selectFiles').files;
  console.log(files);
  if (files.length <= 0) {
    return false;
  }
  
  var fr = new FileReader();
  
  fr.onload = function(e) { 
  console.log(e);
    var result = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
    var formatted = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
        document.getElementById('result').value = formatted;
        var blob = new Blob([formatted], {type: "application/json"});
        var name = "../data/user_network.json";
        saveAs(blob, name);
  }
 
  // remove previous visualization
  d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove();
  
  // create new visualization from user data
  d3.json("../data/user_network.json", function(error, _graph) {
    if (error) throw error;
    graph = _graph;
    initializeDisplay();
    initializeSimulation();
    }); 


};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <label>
        </label>
        <link href="main.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css"/>
        <script src="FileSaver.js"></script>
        <script src="https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/src/FileSaver.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
          <div class = "data">
            <div class = "selection">
                <p><label>data</label>
                Select a dataset</p>
  
                <select name="ab" id="mySelect" onchange="if (this.selectedIndex) select_data(this.selectedIndex);">
                  <option value="-1">--</option>
                  <option value="1">Option1</option> 
                  <option value="2">Option2</option>
                  <option value="3">Option3</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="uploading">
                <p><label>json</label>
                    Upload your dataset in .json</p>
                <input type="file" id="selectFiles" value="Import" /><br />
                <button id="import">Build a network</button> </br>
                <textarea id="result" placeholder="Data preview"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <svg></svg>
          <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
          <script src="../js/code.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot store files on a server using only client-side JavaScript. Your question is not clear. Do you use any server-side technology? Do you really want to store something on the server?

Comment: In addition to @NineBerry 's comment. Even if you save this on your ***server***, you need to specify how you are deploying this. Any proper platform such as ```AWS``` or ```Azure``` will purge all the files on the server on restart so you really should be saving to a remote file system such as ```S3``` or ```Azure Blob```

Comment: @NineBerry I was trying to do it using JavaScript only. Now I understand that I should use Node.js or something like that. I would like to avoid saving the file on the server if it's possible to build a visualization right away.

Comment: @sinanspd That's good to know. I wasn't thinking about deployment yet, I'm only getting started with js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am building an application where a user can upload a JSON file and visualise it on one click

You don't. D3 is quite capable of using [data in variables](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/d3js/data-binding-in-d3js).

> I realize I need to save the file on my server before visualizing it.

If you really want to do that then you need to use `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` to send the stringified JSON to the server, and write server side code (in whatever language you like) to save it.

```
const files = document.getElementById('selectFiles').files;
const data = new FormData();
data.append("json", files[0]);
fetch("http://your-server.example.com/upload-file/", { 
    method: "POST",
    body: data
});
.then( () => { /* process response and do whatever else you want */ } );
```